# Backup Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, devops, etcd

- Kubernetes version: `1.21.0`
- Cloud being used: `bare-metal`
- Installation method: `kubeadm`
- Host OS: `centos 7`
- CNI version: `Flannel v0.3.1`
- CRI and version: `Docker v20.10.7`

How to backup `etcd` in my current setup?

The `etcdcl` command gives an error:

```
-bash: etcdctl: command not found
```

The `etcdctl` command doesn’t work in my current setup please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `etcdctl` on your local machine.

Please follow [etcd installation documentation](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.5/install/#install-pre-built-binaries).

For instance you can find v.3.5.0 [here](https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/releases/tag/v3.5.0) with instuctions.

---

As for backing up the `etcd` you can refer to [kubernetes documentation - Backing up an etcd cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/configure-upgrade-etcd/#backing-up-an-etcd-cluster)

Also you may consider using some dedicated solutions to fully backup kubernetes cluster. One of the examples is [Velero](https://velero.io/)

Comment: It's much more convenient to run `etcdctl` from the same image that is used to run etcd cluster: then you don't need to install anything locally

Comment: Yes it does... Thanks a lot @WytrzymałyWiktor